# Showing Elevation Mapdeck

Tags: r, mapdeck

I require some help in getting my elevation to show in mapdeck. For some reason I cant seem to get the code to work. I can show the points on the map as 2D points using "add_scatterplot" but whenever I try and get it to use the elevation data it does not appear to work and I keep getting the same error.
Here is my code and said error:

```
     mapdeck( token = key, style = mapdeck_style("satellite"), location = c(-2, 57.22),
     zoom = 12,
          pitch = 35) %>% 
     add_scatterplot(
     data = turbines, 
     fill_colour = "Turbine_identifier",
     palette = "green2red") %>% 
     add_trips(
     data = sf_harriers,
     stroke_colour = "TrackId",
     animation_speed = 14,
     trail_length = 80,
     opacity = 1,
     stroke_width = 2,
     palette = colourvalues::get_palette("heat")[6:13, ]) %>% 
   add_column (
   data = turbines,
   lat = "latitude",
   lon = "longitude",
   elevation = "hub_height",
   elevation_scale = 100,
   update_view = FALSE)
```

The error that spits out is:

```
""Error in if (nrow(df) != nrow(.data)) { : argument is of length zero""
```

Which I dont understand as if I plot it without the last layer it plots fine. However when i use "add_column" to then try and get those points to display in 3D using their elevation, it keeps ringing that error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi there, I have added that information. Appreciate the help in figuring this out. The elevation is under "hub_height"

Comment: Hi SYmbolix, thats that updated now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message you're seeing is from `tibble::add_column()`. Therefore you have a conflict in libraries, which you would have been warned about when loading one or the other

```r
library(tibble)

Attaching package: ‘tibble’

The following object is masked from ‘package:mapdeck’:

    add_column
```

So it looks like you've loaded `tidyerse` or `tibble` AFTER `mapdeck`, so the `add_column()` function you're calling is actually `tibble::add_column()`. Change this to `mapdeck::add_column()` and your code works.